# Extract One letter and three numbers from .txt files using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, extract

I would like to extract from many .txt files a certain data in Notepad++.
It has a lot of data in one file, but I only need specific...

This is what looks like in a file:

> ©Q Ńü  Vý    8      ź)  €G' €\Y €   €w) €â` €         K¶  K¶}Ąg†        ‚Z™y  ë(  \Y
>    SCfsfgh4GHGH1+  €‡Ş € €   €?° €¸ €        k k €               ‡Ş  b        | -A233 ™ž    B¤             ˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙  ’        ˙   rtSdpeRB    ˙      GÚS)PS   3: TRANSMIT FILE created by modeller version 1101322   SCH_900000_9008               @Ź@

And I need to extract this:

> A233

TIP: There is a space before - sign ( -A233)
     Also, every file has different numbers next to letter A

In the original file looks like this (a lot of spaces are extracted via copy-paste):
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this a binary file? What do you want to do with the data when you have it? Is it always in the same format (letter + 3 numbers)? Does it always have `| -` before it?

Comment: I want to compare it with the database. Yes, it is always the same format as you said, also | - is always before. Regarding binary file question, I am not familiar with that so I can't answer you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace (ctrl-h) with the following:

Find what: `.*? -(A\d+)`

Replace with: `\1\n`

Check the box for ". matches newline" if they exist in your files

**Explanation:**

`.*? -` - Finds everything up to " -", including any newlines

`(A\d+)` - Defines a capture group that finds A followed immediately by 1 or more numbers

`\1\n` - Replaces matches with the captured number and a newline for separating them

You can swap out the `\n` with the delimiter of your choice

Note that this will not delete any text after the last match, but since you're already in a text editor deleting it is trivial.

Comment: No, I want to extract the numbers next to letter A, because each file has a different numbers. I want them to be extracted so that i can compare them to the database...

Comment: Sorry, but that is not working for, I get some weird numbers... It matches in each line... I've uploaded some of the files, so if you have time you can check it for yourself. http://www.filedropper.com/test_63 Thank you once more!

Comment: @kiki1989sb: Just tried to download your data but can't see a link. Do I need an account? Rather not sign up unless required...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have many .txt files, it makes sense to do a simple automation instead of extracting the values from each file manually. I suggest to use the WSH VBScript below:

```vb
strRes = ""
For Each strPath In WScript.Arguments
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FileExists(strPath) Then
            strRes = strRes & .GetFileName(strPath) & vbCrLf
            strCont = LoadTextFromFile(strPath, "us-ascii")
            With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = "-A(\d{3})"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strCont)
                For Each objMatch In objMatches
                    strRes = strRes & objMatch.SubMatches(0) & vbCrLf
                Next
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next
ShowInNotepad strRes

Function LoadTextFromFile(strPath, strCharset)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' TypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile strPath
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = strCharset
        LoadTextFromFile = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub ShowInNotepad(strToFile)
    Dim strTempPath
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strTempPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\" & .GetTempName
        With .CreateTextFile(strTempPath, True, True)
            .WriteLine strToFile
            .Close
        End With
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe " & strTempPath, 1, True
        .DeleteFile (strTempPath)
    End With
End Sub
```

Just paste this code to the notepad, save as text file, and manually replace `.txt` file extension with `.vbs`. Then all that you need is select your text files in explorer window, and drag and drop them onto the script.

For the files you have shared I has the output as follows:

> 30_SCH51BQ139.txt
>
> 036
>
> 30_SCH51BQ141.txt
>
> 038
>
> 30_SCH51BQ144.txt
>
> 040
>
> 30_SCH51BQ147.txt
>
> 043

Comment: Thnak you for the VBS script. I have already solved this in excel via VB, but because of macros (security) I have to make it via notepad++